Getting the TC filter for TCP dest port to work
I was try to configure a TC filter to act upon any TCP packet that is going to 5201.
My statement goes as follows:
$ tc filter add dev enp1s0 protocol ip parent 1:0 u32 match tcp dst 0x1451 0xffff flowid 1:10
This statement does not work..
However, when I use the following, it works:
$ tc filter add dev enp1s0 protocol ip parent 1:0 u32 match ip protocol 6 ff match ip dport 0x1451 0xffff flowid 1:10
I would like to know why the latter command works and not the former...??
Thank in advance for your comments.
